# How do I display detailed table on the basis of inputs from three different summary tables using DT / renderDataTable() in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, interactive

I have three different dataframes showing altogether different data with different number of rows and columns.  I have displayed all of them one below other in left column of shiny screen.  On the right side, I want to display a detailed dataframe, depending upon the selected rows of the selected table (out of three) on left hand side.

`input$tableId_cell_clicked` and `input$tableId_rows_selected` are very much useful, if I have to choose from one dataframe and display other dataframe on the basis of row selected or cell clicked.

Is there any input parameter which will help me to get the table / dataframe (out of three) in which the user has clicked along with the cell or row selected.  That will enable me to display the detailed table on right hand side of shiny screen, based on the table and row input by the user?

Example given below:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)                     # datatable()
library(shinydashboard)


ui <-fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE, width = NULL, collapsed = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(            
      fixedRow(
        column(4, 
               dataTableOutput("summary_abc"), 
               dataTableOutput("summary_def"), 
               dataTableOutput("summary_ghi")),
        column(5, 
               textOutput("employee_details")))
    )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$summary_abc <- renderDataTable({
    options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 10, searching = FALSE, paging = FALSE))
    
    employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
    salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
    age <- c(45,63,28)
    data1 <- data.frame(employee, salary, age)
    
    table_1 <- data1
    table_1 <- datatable(table_1, class = 'cell-border stripe', selection = "single",
                         options = list(ordering=F, dom = 't'),
                         caption = "Summary 1", rownames = FALSE)
    table_1})
  
  output$summary_def <- renderDataTable({
    options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 10, searching = FALSE, paging = FALSE))
    
    employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
    qualification <- c("Graduate", "Post Graduate", "Master")
    experience <- c(8,5,17)
    data2 <- data.frame(employee, qualification, experience)
    
    table_1 <- data2
    table_1 <- datatable(table_1, class = 'cell-border stripe', selection = "single",
                         options = list(ordering=F, dom = 't'),
                         caption = "Summary 2", rownames = FALSE)
    table_1})
  
  output$summary_ghi <- renderDataTable({
    options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 10, searching = FALSE, paging = FALSE))
    
    employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope', "Jackson")
    weight <- c(60,58,72,59)
    temperature <- c(95,97,96,98)
    data3 <- data.frame(employee, weight, temperature)
    
    table_1 <- data3
    table_1 <- datatable(table_1, class = 'cell-border stripe', selection = "single",
                         options = list(ordering=F, dom = 't'),
                         caption = "Summary 3", rownames = FALSE)
    table_1})
  
  
  output$employee_details <- renderText(
    {
      table_selected <- "Summary 2"
      row_selected <- 3
      paste("Table: ", table_selected, "Row: ", row_selected)
      
    }
  )
  
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You could filter the 3 dataframes based on the row the user clicks and combine all 3 selected rows in a new dataframe which you can display on the right. To really help you, could you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Hi Thomas,  Thanks for the response.  Please see the appended example.  I want to extract table name and row number selected by the user.

Comment: Thanks for the example! For the next time, try to reduce as much code as possible, then it's easier to directly focus on your question. Here all the CSS and JS code and the reactable package are totally irrelevant for solving your problem

Comment: That's working fine, exactly what I wanted.  Thanks. I will keep in mind to post limited code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reactive value to save the latest table click and arbitrary further information on every change.

Add this to your server function and change your text output:

```r
table_reac <- reactiveValues()
observeEvent(input$summary_abc_rows_selected, {
  table_reac$title <- "Summary 1"
  table_reac$row <- input$summary_abc_rows_selected
})
observeEvent(input$summary_def_rows_selected, {
  table_reac$title <- "Summary 2"
  table_reac$row <- input$summary_def_rows_selected
})
observeEvent(input$summary_ghi_rows_selected, {
  table_reac$title <- "Summary 3"
  table_reac$row <- input$summary_ghi_rows_selected
})

output$employee_details <- renderText(
  {
    table_selected <- table_reac$title
    row_selected <- table_reac$row
    
    paste("Table: ", table_selected, "Row: ", row_selected)
    
  }
)
```